# How to uninstall an app in flutter programatically?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, launcher

I am building a launcher app in flutter. But I couldn't add the uninstall feature. Please help me.

Comment: you can't *uninstall* the app. You can only ask the system app named *Package Manager* to start uninstall progress, where the user will have to confirm he wahts to uninstall it.

Comment: How to do that? Can you help? I did it worked in Native Java but don't know how to do it in dart.

Comment: Are you able to send intents in dart? If you are able, then you should be OK to just send the correct intent, same as in Java

Comment: I am trying but still not sure about the possibility.

Comment: I am trying this but I don't know it will work or not https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec

Comment: hi @AmonChowdhury did you find any solution?

Comment: @VickySalunkhe nope

Comment: @AmonChowdhury I have found a way to do it, do give it a try and accept the answer if it works :)

Answer (score 6):

Add a permission in `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

add a package in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
intent: ^1.3.4
```

Use the below shown code and

To uninstall an app pass the package name to it. `$packageName` is a variable
ex, `some.app.id`

```
android_intent.Intent()
  ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_DELETE)
  ..setData(Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
  ..startActivityForResult().then((data) {
    print(data);
  }, onError: (e) {
    print(e);
  });
```

using this a system generated popup will occur asking to uninstall the app.

So using this you can uninstall apps on your android device using flutter programmatically.

Comment: It's for android only, haven't tested for iOS

Comment: Don't bother. iOS doesn't allow that.

Comment: This package crashes my app after two attempts of uninstall, if you also faced the issue then you can search for uninstall apps in pub.dev and download the package that is updated recently to solve this error, this is intent specific issue. Also the package provided by flutter team named as android_intent doesn't support deletion of package currently.