# Is there any way I can uninstall an app from my device using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, uninstallation

I am using *device_apps* to list the available apps on my device. I want to uninstall an app by tapping on the Icon button, is there any way I can do the same?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPHiC.jpg)

Comment: You can't do it inside your app..
Refer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163793/how-to-uninstall-an-app-in-flutter-programatically

Answer (score 1):

Answer inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163793/how-to-uninstall-an-app-in-flutter-programatically) and by [@Vicky Salunkhe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9236994/vicky-salunkhe)

To uninstall an app pass the package name to it. `$packageName` is a variable ex, `some.app.id`

```
android_intent.Intent()
  ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_DELETE)
  ..setData(Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
  ..startActivityForResult().then((data) {
    print(data);
  }, onError: (e) {
    print(e);
  });
```

add a package in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
intent: ^1.3.4
```

permission in `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

Read more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163793/how-to-uninstall-an-app-in-flutter-programatically) and can also refer [here](https://pub.dev/packages/app_uninstaller)