# Flutter:I can uninstall an app using android_action.Action.ACTION_DELETE .But after uninstallation restarts my whole app, how handle this issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I have used following package to uninstall any app inside my flutter app:

```
android_intent.Intent()
  ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_DELETE)
  ..setData(Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
  ..startActivityForResult().then((data) {
    print(data);
  }, onError: (e) {
    print(e);
  });
```

Here is the link to the original Question : [Uninstall app in flutter using android intent][1]

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163793/how-to-uninstall-an-app-in-flutter-programatically/62196226?![AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163793/how-to-uninstall-an-app-in-flutter-programatically/62196226?!%5BAndroidManifest.xml) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L3VY.jpg)

Comment: What is the launchMode setting of your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I have included the image of my Android manifest.xml file..... you can see Image above in question description...